# How can I get all the ad groups and users into a Excel worksheet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The problem with this code is that for each folder, I only get 1 group or 1 user depending on the folder (mostly the last one), while I want to get all the  security groups, and members of the folder, for each folder in the drive.

```cs
$title = "ADPermissions.csv"
$title2 = "ADPermissions2.csv"
$ss =$Selection1 -replace '[\W]', ''
$subtitle = "HardDrive"+ $ss
$exclude = @("BUILTIN|NT AUTHORITY|EVERYONE|CREATOR OWNER|NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM|SYSTEM")


$OutFile = ($Selection2+"\"+$subtitle+$title)
Write-Host = $OutFile

if(Test-Path $OutFile -PathType Leaf)
{
    $result3 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("The file already exists in the selected path`n"+"Do you want to delete it and proceed ?",'File already exists','YesNoCancel','Exclamation')

if ($result3 = "Yes")
{
    Remove-Item $OutFile
    $Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,names"

    $RootPath = $Selection

    $Folders = dir $RootPath  | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

#To the point:

    try {
        
        foreach ($Folder in $Folders){$ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  } | where {$_.identityreference -notmatch $exclude}
            Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
     
                $strAcls = $ACL.IdentityReference.ToString()
                $strUsers=@()
                $strNames=$strAcls.Remove(0,12)
        
                $user = $(try {Get-ADUser $strNames} catch {$null})
                if ($strNames -ne $null -and $user -eq $null) {                
                    $A += Get-ADGroupMember -identity $strNames -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Property DisplayName | Select Name | Sort-Object Name           
                } else {
        
                }
                foreach ($env:USERNAME in $A){
                    $strUsers +=$env:USERNAME
                }
                $OutInfo =  $Folder.fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + $strUsers
        
            }   
        
            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile | sort-Object 
        
        }
    }catch [System.IO.IOException] {
        
    }
}
```

> I:\Dropbox,GESCOEUROPE\GR_G-FCASB-INT-ALL@{Name=CAPPUCCILLI FEDERICO}
> @{Name=De Fruyt Frederik}
>
> I:\General,GESCOEUROPE\GR_G-FCASB-INT-ADMIN@{Name=CAPPUCCILLI
> FEDERICO} @{Name=De Fruyt Frederik@{Name=VANDEWALLE MARIA}
> @{Name=VANSTEELANDT LUCRECE}
>
> I:\ICT,GESCOEUROPE\GR_G-FCASB-INT-ADMIN@{Name=CAPPUCCILLI FEDERICO}
> @{Name=De Fruyt Frederik} @{Name=FREDERIK DE FRUYT (ADM)}
> @{Name=GAILITE ZANETE} @{Name=Geldhof Francine} @{Name=GOEMAERE
> GWENNY}
>
> I:\PaymentFollow-Up,GESCOEUROPE\GR_G-FCASB-INT-ALL@{Name=CAPPUCCILLI
> FEDERICO}
>
> this is the output i get, as you see for each folder I have only 1
> group, But thats incorrect because some folders have more than 1 group

Comment: The code seems incomplete or at least there is some parenthesis issues i thied to clean up. If this is wrong please [edit] it correctly. Namely I wanted to remove the huge amount of whitespace.

Comment: It might be easier to just re-write the whole thing. I see at least half a dozens problems/issues. Can you show an example of what the output is supposed to look like. Are you trying to get a list of non standard permissions on folders?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Adding to that you are not appending the data. YOu seems overwriting the existing one